# faster way to sync the members of 2 class (the same type of class)

Tags: c++, class, synchronization

I have a class defined as:

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:
ExampleClass(HWND hwnd);
~ExampleClass();
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

which has many members. Later, I created 2 pointers:

```
ExampleClass *example1 = new ExampleClass(hwndFrame1);
ExampleClass *example2 = new ExampleClass(hwndFrame2);
```

Here `hwndFrame1` and `hwndFrame2` are handles of two different windows.

At some point, I need to sync the values of all the members of these two classes pointed by `example1` and `example2`. Of course I can do this each member by each member. But I wonder if there is a "one-go" solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking any further information I would suggest:

```
*example2 = *example1;
```

If `ExampleClass` is using the compiler declared copy assignment operator this should do a memberwise copy, otherwise it should do "the appropriate thing". Obviously the two objects being pointed to will refer to the same underlying window after this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Charles Bailey's answer you can also implement a sync of two objects yourself by doing:

```
memcpy(example2, example1, sizeof(ExampleClass));
```

Afterwards you can eventually set back the window pointer (assuming you don't want to sync these as well), like below:

```
HWND wnd = example2->window;
memcpy(example2, example1, sizeof(ExampleClass));
example2->window = wnd;
```

You can implement this in your ExampleClass copy assignment operator (like Charles Bailey suggested) but I would not recommend this, as it does not assign the window pointer and thus is not a real assignment. Instead, just implement it in a separate function or method. Note that this in general only works if both objects are of the exact same class!